# Negating this statement: For all $n\geq 1$, there exist two strictly positive sequences $(y_n)$ and $(z_n)$ such that ...

Tags: logic

Let $(x_n)$ be a strictly positive sequence of real numbers.

> I want to find the negation of the following statement:
>
> > For all $n\geq 1$, there exist two strictly positive sequences $(y_n)$ and $(z_n)$ such that $0<y_n<x_n$ and $0<z_n<x_n$ and $x_n=y_n+z_n$.

Comment: The negation of "For all x, There exists y such that ..." is "There is x such that For all y not ..."

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: what about the inequalities and the equation!

Comment: You do not know how to negate $a < b$ ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: I think that the inequalties are unchanged

Comment: Why not just choose $y_n=z_n=x_n/2$?  That statement is not a "case" it is something that always is true.

Comment: The negation is simply that for some sequence $(x_n)$ there do not exists sequences $(y_n),(z_n)$ with the stated properties.

Comment: @Michael The OP is not asking how to prove the statement, but what its negation is.

Comment: @saulspatz : The statement is just a true statement, its negation is $1=0$.

Comment: PS: I am reading the "Let $(x_n)$ be a strictely positive sequence" as part of the given info and not part of the statement itself. If the asker just wanted a logical negation of the statement itself, it is not clear why that extra info was given (particularly the part about $x_n$ being strictly positive).

Comment: You have to take into account that the clause to be negated is a set of "and" and also the inequality $0 < y_n < x_n$ aìis and "and". Thus, you need a suitable application of De Morgan Law.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll start if off and see if you can take it from here.

There exists an $n\geq1$, so that for all two strictely positive sequences $(y_n)$ and $(z_n)$, it is not the case that, $(0<y_n<x_n)$ and $(0<z_n<x_n)$ and $(x_n=y_n+z_n)$ (i.e one of those fails).

See if you can finish off by distributing the negation to the conjunction.
i.e $\neg(A\wedge B\wedge C)\equiv\ ...$

Also I don't think you want to put the universal first, I'm guessing you want to say something like this instead:

There exists two strictly positive sequences $(y_n)$ and $(z_n)$ such that for all $n\geq1$ we have that $(0<y_n<x_n)$ and $(0<z_n<x_n)$ and $(x_n=y_n+z_n)$.

Then the negation of the statement becomes:

For all two strictly positive sequences $(y_n)$ and $(z_n)$ there exists some $n\geq1$ where it is not the case that, $(0<y_n<x_n)$ and $(0<z_n<x_n)$ and $(x_n=y_n+z_n)$.